# Adding index of records in a Javafx Tableview column

Tags: java, xml, javafx, unmarshalling

I am extracting the data from an xml file using a Wrapper for the my Model Class.

Model Class:

```
private final StringProperty fileSubject;
private final StringProperty fileDate;
private final StringProperty fileRemarks;

public void setFileSubject(String fileSubject){
    this.fileSubject.set(fileSubject);
}
public String getFileSubject() {
    return fileSubject.get();
}
public StringProperty fileSubjectProperty() {
    return fileSubject;
}

public void setFileDate(String fileDate){
    this.fileDate.set(fileDate);
}
public String getFileDate() {
    return fileDate.get();
}
public StringProperty fileDateProperty() {
    return fileDate;
}

public void setFileRemarks(String fileRemarks){
    this.fileRemarks.set(fileRemarks);
}
public String getFileRemarks() {
    return fileRemarks.get();
}
public StringProperty fileRemarksProperty(){
    return fileRemarks;
}

/**
* Default constructor.
*/
public FileModel(){
    this(null,null, null);
}

/**
*Constructor with some initial data.
*
*@param 
*
*/

public FileModel(String fileSubject, String fileDate, String fileRemarks){
    this.fileSubject = new SimpleStringProperty(fileSubject);
    this.fileDate = new SimpleStringProperty(fileDate);
    this.fileRemarks = new SimpleStringProperty(fileRemarks);
}

}
```

Wrapper Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "files")
public class FileListWrapper {

private List<FileModel> files;

@XmlElement(name = "file")
public List<FileModel> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(List<FileModel> files) {
    this.files = files;
}

}
```

That is how I am unmarshalling it:

```
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(FileListWrapper.class);
 Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
 File file = new File("xxxxxxxxxx/xxx/x/xxxx/x.xml");
        // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
        FileListWrapper wrapper = (FileListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);
        fileData.clear();
        fileData.addAll(wrapper.getFiles());
```

Now I am adding the extracted data into the tableview as below:

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){
    //Initialize the file table with the three columns.

    indexColumn = new TableColumn<>("Index");
    indexColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<FileModel, Void> cell = new TableCell<>();
        cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (cell.isEmpty()) {
                return null ;
            } else {
                return Integer.toString(cell.getIndex());
            }
        }));
        return cell ;
    });

fileTable.getColumns().add(0, indexColumn);

    fileSubjectColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fileSubjectProperty());
    fileDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fileDateProperty());

     fileTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
           (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showFileDetails(newValue));
    showFileDetails(null);

}

/**
*Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
*
*@param mainApp
*/
public void setMainApp(MainAppClass mainApp){
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    FilteredList<FileModel> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getFileData(), p -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(files -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all files.
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Compare File Subject and Date of every file with filter text.
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if (files.getFileSubject().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                return true; // Filter matches Subject.
            }
                else if (files.getFileDate().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });

    // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
    SortedList<FileModel> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

    // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(fileTable.comparatorProperty());

    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.

    fileTable.setItems(sortedData);

}
```

Now, the `indexColumn` doesn't displays any index. Kindly, help me out with it. I have tried multiple things but its not working out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the index is just the index of the element in the table's item list. So you can do

```
TableColumn<FileModel, Void> indexCol = new TableColumn<>("Index");
indexCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
    TableCell<FileModel, Void> cell = new TableCell<>();
    cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        if (cell.isEmpty()) {
            return null ;
        } else {
            return Integer.toString(cell.getIndex() + 1);
        }
    }, cell.emptyProperty(), cell.indexProperty()));
    return cell ;
});
```

Complete example (using standard Oracle tutorial example):

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewWithIndexColumn extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson",
                        "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));



        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = createColumn("First Name",
                Person::firstNameProperty, 150);
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = createColumn("Last Name",
                Person::lastNameProperty, 150);
        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = createColumn("Email",
                Person::emailProperty, 150);

        // index column doesn't even need data...
        TableColumn<Person, Void> indexCol = new TableColumn<>("Index");
        indexCol.setPrefWidth(50);

        // cell factory to display the index:
        indexCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
            
            // just a default table cell:
            TableCell<Person, Void> cell = new TableCell<>();
            
            cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                if (cell.isEmpty()) {
                    return null ;
                } else {
                    return Integer.toString(cell.getIndex() + 1);
                }
            }, cell.emptyProperty(), cell.indexProperty()));
            
            return cell ;
        });

        table.getColumns().add(indexCol);
        table.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(emailCol);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createColumn(String title,
            Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property, double width) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setPrefWidth(width);
        return col;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person() {
            this("", "", "");
        }

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nah!!! it is not displaying the data in the column and not even creating the column named "Index".

Comment: This is the sample for my code: [link](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part5/)  @James_D

Comment: Can't check that right now, but I assume you added the column to the table...?

Comment: I have tried it in multiple ways but its not helping.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. It works fine in my example. You probably need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) specifically for this issue.

Comment: I don't see where you are adding `indexCol` to the `fileTable`  Again, if you could create an MCVE it would really help.

Comment: I have edited it again actually while updating last time I mistakenly removed `fileTable.getColumns().add(0, indexColumn);`.

Comment: Ah, looks like I somehow missed specifying the bound properties in `Bindings.createStringBinding(...)`. See update.